# Windows 10 mklink to c:/originalDirectory which preserves original files if they are deleted from the linked directory

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, junction, mklink, directory-junction

I'm on Windows 10.

Imagine that I have a directory `c:\originalDirectory` and I create a link at `c:\newDirectory` by doing `mklink /d c:\newDirectory c:\originalDirectory`.

My question is about the files that live inside a linked directory. When I delete `c:\newDirectory\exampleFile.jpg`, the original file is also deleted at `c:\originalDirectory\exampleFile.jpg`. Of course, the link itself `c:\newDirectory` is not removed.

Doing a directory junction with `mklink /j c:\newDirectory c:\originalDirectory` results in the same behavior.

Is there some form of link or file synchronization mechanism wherein if I delete `c:\newDirectory\exampleFile.jpg`, the original file at `c:\originalDirectory\exampleFile.jpg` is preserved? Of course, I would also want to preserve the link itself at `c:\newDirectory`.

I recognize that if I create a links to the individual files themselves by doing `mklink c:\newDirectory\linkToExampleFile.jpg` `c:\originalDirectory\exampleFile.jpg`, I can delete `c:\newDirectory\linkToExampleFile.jpg` without deleting `c:\originalDirectory\exampleFile.jpg`. But there are A LOT of files in `c:\originalDirectory` so creating a link to each file doesn't seem like a great option.

Comment: I don't know who keeps downvoting here, but I'm out of this post.

Comment: @harrymc I don't see any aggressive behaviour here. T.J.L is patiently trying to help you write better answers. You would do well to pay heed to their advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that I've come up with is to use Microsoft SyncToy to synchronize the folders while preventing any deletions in the right folder, `c:\newDirectory`, from deleting files in the left folder, `c:\originalDirectory`. However, this solution uses twice the amount of disc space because the files live in both folders.

Comment: A shame that this has to be the workaround. Or, @ninja star, have you been able to find an neater solution?

Comment: I use *nix now, for that, here's a good option to explore: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount/198591#198591